# Return subclass when superclass is defined as return type

Tags: java, list, data-structures, extends

In extension of a question about the same topic: [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)
I had a follow-up question.

Given that you have classes
Animal - parent
Dog - child

Why can't you return a List when you defined your return type as List?

```
    private class Animal{};

    private class Dog extends Animal{};

      public List<Animal> makeAnimalListOfDogs(Dog dog1, Dog dog2){
            List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>;
            dogs.add(dog1);
            dogs.add(dog2);
            return dogs;
        }
```

This might seem a useless example, but it is just to clarify the problem. If you try this, you will get the error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Dog> to List<Animal>
```

It is off course possible by replacing `return dogs` by the following snippet

```
List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animals>();
animals.addAll(dogs)
return animals;
```

So the problem is not how to make this work, but WHY doesn't it work.
The list dogs IS a list containing animals, given the fact that a dog is an animal, right?

Comment: How is this question different from the question you linked to?

Comment: See John Skeet's answer to the question that you linked to yourself. If you don't understand something about that answer, you should be specific in your question what it is that you have problems with. "No, a List<Dog> is not a List<Animal>. Consider what you can do with a List<Animal> - you can add any animal to it... including a cat. Now, can you logically add a cat to a litter of puppies? Absolutely not." (John Skeet)

Answer (score 0):

See [John Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745301/14955) to the question that you linked to yourself:

---

No, a `List<Dog>` is *not* a `List<Animal>`. Consider what you can do with a `List<Animal>` - you can add *any* animal to it... including a cat. Now, can you logically add a cat to a litter of puppies? Absolutely not.

```
// Illegal code - because otherwise life would be Bad
List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>();
List<Animal> animals = dogs; // Awooga awooga
animals.add(new Cat());
Dog dog = dogs.get(0); // This should be safe, right?
```

Suddenly you have a *very* confused cat.

Now, you *can't* add a `Cat` to a `List<? extends Animal>` because you don't know it's a `List<Cat>`. You can retrieve a value and know that it will be an `Animal`, but you can't add arbitrary animals. The reverse is true for `List<? super Animal>` - in that case you can add an `Animal` to it safely, but you don't know anything about what might be retrieved from it, because it could be a `List<Object>`.